# Generating Jenkins Pipeline Stages from pytest

Tags: groovy, jenkins-pipeline, pytest

Is it possible/is there a plugin to dynamically create jenkins pipeline stages from pytest?
(run pytest in a pipeline, and then every test that pytest runs will create a new stage in the pipeline, so the blue ocean view of the jenkins job will have created stages for all the tests)

I probably could list all the tests that will run, and then run them manually in parallel, something like this:

```
stage("Run Tests"){
   steps {
    script {
     def tests = sh(script: "pytest tests/ --collect-only", returnStdout: true).trim().split().toList()
     // manipulate tests so that I have a dictionary of filename - test name
     run_tests = [:]
     tests.each { test ->  //test[0] is file name and test[1] is test name
         run_tests[test[1]] = {
             stage(test[1]) {
               sh "pytest ${test[0]} -k ${test[1]}"
             }
         }
     }
     parallel run_tests
   }
  } 
}
```

but it would be easier if there was a native way to do this within pytest or within Jenkins

Thank you!

Comment: What problem do you experience with the above solution? For me it looks valid, except that you are missing a `stage` block for getting a good visualization in BlueOcean: `run_tests[test[1]] = { stage(test[1]) { sh "pytest ${test[0]} -k ${test[1]}" } }`

Comment: @Zwtt42 Thanks for the edit. (I will edit the post)
Doing this way requires me to manually parse all the tests, and there could be other flags or options that I might miss.
I just wanted to know if there was a `test-to-stage` option somewhere that would do this in a cleaner and more native way. 
Perhaps there is not.

Comment: I don't see a cleaner way.